# Cannot load .vtt file, Firefox security error, and Chrome MIME type error

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, webvtt

I am trying to use captions or subtitles on HTML5 video, but it's not working.  When the *.vtt file is loaded, I get errors. In Firefox, the error is:

*Security Error: Content at file:///C:/.../index.html may not load data from file:///C:/.../my_captions.vtt.*

In Chrome, the error message is:

*Resource interpreted as TextTrack but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "file:///C:/.../my_captions.vtt".*

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
    <title>Video</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Video</h2>
    <video width="96%" controls preload="metadata">
      <source src="video-720.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      <track
        type="text/vtt"
        label="English"
        kind="subtitles"
        srclang="en"
        src="my_captions.vtt"
        default
      />
    </video>
  </body>
</html>
```

I added the `type="text/vtt"` to the track tag, but it didn't help.  (MDN does not show 'type' as an attribute for the track tag, but does show the MIME type for .vtt files as [text/vtt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebVTT_API))

The video plays as expected.  In Firefox, the 'cc' button is shown on the controls, but not in Chrome.  Both browsers are finding the .vtt file, but won't read it.  The problem does not appear to be the format of the .vtt file:

```
WEBVTT - Test file

00:03.000 --> 00:06.000 align:middle line:90%
This is a caption

00:08.000 --> 00:12.000 align:middle line:90%
Do this and that

00:15.000 --> 00:22.000 align:middle line:90%
Do this and that
```

I haven't seen any information anywhere regarding these errors when reading .vtt files. All the files are local, in the same folder.  When I load them directly into the browsers, they show the text with no errors.  Why is this not working?

Comment: Start a local web server, you'll win a lot of time. Having to workaround such issues now means that you will have to come back to these workarounds at deployment.

Comment: It works using XAMPP, but I don't see how this helps.  I'm creating an Ionic-React app hosted on FIrebase.  I couldn't get the captions to work, so I stripped it down to the simplest form I could to figure it out - just an HTML file on a local browser.

I don't know what 'workarounds' are needed at deployment.  I haven't deployed anything to FIrebase yet, so I don't know it the captions will work when hosted there.